# PHP - header redirect not working under ssl

Tags: php, redirect

I have simple php code:

```
<?php
    /* Redirect browser */

    $url = urldecode($_GET['redirect']);

    if (empty($url)) { 
        echo "no url";
    } else {
        header("Location: $url");
    }

    /* Make sure that code below does not get executed when we redirect. */

    exit;
?>
```

When I type:

```
http://domain.com/r.php?redirect=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.pl
```

I got redirected to google. But when I access url via https:

```
https://domain.com/r.php?redirect=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.pl
```

I am redirected to domain root, f.e `domain.com`. Everything else is working fine with https.

What is wrong?

**EDIT:** it seems that redirection to relative url works fine - only aboslute url over https causes problems.

Comment: Your web server, which is handling the HTTPS connection, is somehow misconfigured...!?

Comment: You don't need to [urldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php#refsect1-function.urldecode-notes) `$_GET` variables as they are decoded automatically. This can lead to unwanted results

Comment: It would be very strange. I can access it without querystring (then `no url` is printed on page) - so script is executed. It is possible to make apache ignore part of header and overwrite it?

Comment: False - alarm - it didn't helped.

Comment: Have you tried different URL-s? Maybe it didn't work before and browser cached the wrong redirection?

Comment: @ErkiA yes-  the same problem. It seems, that apache is badly configured.

Comment: Check the request in browser's network inspector. Try adding proper HTTP status code.

Comment: I have checked it already. The location header in server response is already changed to root domain desipte in php code other url was written.